# How do I configure cross-compile toolchain on QtCreator?

Tags: qt, arm, cross-compiling

I have built a Qt toolchain using Yocto. I installed it and set the environment variables running the script generated by Yocto.

I open QtCreator and [configure my cross-compiler kit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqAnS.png) following these [instructions](http://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/how-to-set-up-qt-creator-to-cross-compile-for-embedded-linux#Configure_Qt_Creator). 
I'm unable to build this:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{    
    QApplication a( argc, argv );    
    QPushButton hello( "Hello world!", 0 );
    hello.resize( 100, 30 );
    hello.show();    
    return a.exec();    
}
```

Getting this error:

```
(.qtversion[qt_version_tag]+0x0):-1: error: undefined reference to `qt_version_tag'
```

So I try to build this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   printf("Hello world!\n");
   return 0;
}
```

It's ok. But when I deploy to my target and try to run it can't because it hasn't been compiled for target architecture (arm).

```
helloworld: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ldd
```

There is also this warning which could be very indicative:

```
:-1: warning: "/usr/bin/gcc" is used by qmake, but "/opt/poky/2.1.1/sysroots/i686-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc" is configured in the kit.
Please update your kit or choose a mkspec for qmake that matches your target environment better.
```

<strike>I tried to set mkspec on my kit configuration but the result it's the same.</strike>

Comment: I tried to compile from command line with qmake and it did right. So it's qt creator configuration issue.

Comment: If manually running qmake works then your kit might have the wrong qmake configured

Comment: If I open project configuration > build > system environment: the variables set by setup-enviornment script are there. So I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. Maybe I "lied" about saying that setting the mkspec manually it wasn't working neither. That's not true, it does. It's just I was having another issues and couldn't test it properly. The problem was `mkspec` it wasn't the right. It was pointing to `linux-g++` and I fixed it pointing to the proper mkspec. Anyway Qt cretator is telling me that he [can't find it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hQEc.png)! so it's that a bug? The first issue (compiling GUI) was solved too thanks to this.

Comment: Indeed, it was a bug. Already fixed on 4.3: https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/176005/